# How can scrolling banner work on Android tablet HTML veiwer?

Tags: android, html, plugins, tablet

I am using Dreamweaver plug-in "flevPersistentDivs.mxp" to produce the flash banner up and down which the page scroll pulled flash banner will slide up and down along. The flash banner format is swf. It works on computer when I test it but the banner disappear when I test on Android tablet HTML viewer.How can it works on tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the Android version of Adobe Flash, but since Adobe no longer supports the Android platform, I'd strongly suggest you replace your `swf` with something else, either HTML5 + Javascript or Java code in your Android app.